# OpenCV Inconsistent Image Rotation between Python and C++

Tags: python, c++, python-2.7, opencv

I am working on rotating an image 90 degrees CCW with OpenCV. I started with the Python implementation (`rotate.py`) and then converted it to C++ (`rotate.cpp`). Problem is I'm getting inconsistent results.
I annotated both versions below around the line `getRotationMatrix2D(...)` on both to describe the inconsistency. If I don't follow the described methods below I get image that are rotated but shifted out of frame.

I'm on OpenCV 2.4 and opencv-python 3.4.0.12. 
EDIT: I've also tried with OpenCV 3.4 now with the same results.

---

This image was rotated with `rotate.cpp` with the center of rotation at `Point(x/2, y/2)`.

[image: Bad rotation]

---

rotate.py

```
import sys
import os
import cv2

i = sys.argv[1]
im = cv2.imread(i)
y,x = im.shape[:2]  

# x/2, y/2 can be used for the center
# but then the two lower are required
# This follows a tutorial I read
M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((x/2,y/2), 90, 1)
M[0, 2] += (y / 2) - x/2
M[1, 2] += (x / 2) - y/2

# The center also works as x/2, x/2
# but only if the two lines after are commented out
M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((x/2,x/2), 90, 1)
#M[0, 2] += (y / 2) - x/2
#M[1, 2] += (x / 2) - y/2  

im = cv2.warpAffine(im, M, (y, x))

try:
    cv2.imwrite(i+'~'+'.png', im, params=(cv2.IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION, 5))
except:
    os.remove(i+'~'+'.png')
    continue

try:
    os.rename(i+'~'+'.png', i)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    os.rename(i+'~'+'.png', i)
    raise
```

---

rotate.cpp

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    const auto in_img = cv::imread(argv[1]);
    const auto in_size = in_img.size();

    const auto& x = in_size.width;
    const auto& y = in_size.height;

    decltype(in_img) out_img(x, y, in_img.type());
    const auto out_size = out_img.size();

    //       Only works if these are both x/2      v    v
    cv::Mat M = cv::getRotationMatrix2D(cv::Point(x/2, x/2), 90, 1.0);
    //M.at<int>(0, 2) += ((y/1) - x/2);
    //M.at<int>(1, 2) += ((x/1) - y/2);
    //   ^   Were not having any effect

    cv::warpAffine(in_img, out_img, M, out_size);

    cv::imwrite(std::string(argv[1]) + "~.png", out_img, {CV_IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION, 5});

}
```

Comment: can you be a little clear on your question?

Comment: What are the inconsistent results? can you post some example images with the problem?

Comment: @api55 I uploaded an image of a failed rotation using the C++ version. Whereas the same configuration of `getRotationMatrix2D(...)` in the Python version would give a properly centered image.

Comment: well it not 100% wrong... not sure how you get different results in python though.... if you think about it keeps the center point in the same position, does the rotation and puts the pixels when it cans.... probably -90° would be "good".... you probably have to add in the affine matrix some small shifts to get the correct image. Try your code with a square image, and you should have the expected results

Comment: @api55 -90 Is the same thing, but CW instead of CCW. Since it rotates about the center point `(x/2, y/x)` should work because thats the center (works in Python). But It seems to also work with `(x/2, x/2)` which is not the center.

Comment: with (x/2, x/2) the rotational point is higher so you are already shifting the center point... not sure how does it work internally... but if you rotate this picture in the exact center CCW, part of the picture should be "outside" the image.. not sure if OpenCV can manage it.... but a simple solution is to add translation to your affine matrix (not to the center point)

Comment: @api55 You're right, I worked out whey `x/2 x/2` is the correct center for a `CCW` rotation (because the source and destination images are aligned at the top left and not the center). The affine matrix translation is not working in C++, but it does in Python which is why I could use a center of `x/2 y/2` there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data type of the affine matrix transformation is `double` not `int`. The `at` statement needs to be `M.at<double(...)`.

In order to do a CCW rotation with a center of `(x/2, x/2)`, the matrix needs to be shifted by `1`. `M.at<double>(1,2) -= 1;`
This is because OpenCV considers the top left to be `(0, 0)`.

As an alternative, the affine matrix can be bypassed entirely for rotation in units of 90° using matrix rotation. In python, for example, `img.rot90()`.